# Создание геолокационной игры на Unity

Tags: unity3d-android

Всем здравствуйте. Хочу создать геолокационную игру на подобии Ingress, Pokemon GO, Orna и т.д. только начал изучать все и столкнулся с первым вопросом. Какие есть бесплатные картографические библиотеки, которые помогут мне в создании игры. Знаю есть Mapbox, но она условно бесплатная, понимаю что мне этих ресурсов вполне хватит на первое время, но все же хотелось бы полностью бесплатную либу, чтобы не зависит не думать, превысил ли я бесплатный лимит или нет, как в Mapbox.